# Finding signatue of a symmetric matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Is it possible to find the signature of a matrix without finding the eigenvalues of the matrix?

I was hoping to use the Sylvester's Law of inertia but I don't remember any algorithm to diagonalize a matrix $A$ to the form $UDU^t$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

The actual aim was to find the number of real solutions of a uni-variate polynomial using Pederson-Roy-Szpirglas theorem. http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-2752-6_15

Comment: One way to do it is to write down the quadratic form corresponding to your matrix, and complete the square.

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: @Asal Can provide reference to some text on this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to compute the LU decomposition (without pivoting) of the symmetric matrix and count the signs on the diagonal of the U factor. This of course fails if some early diagonal entry of U is $0$.

---

Justification: Decompose $U=DR$ with $D$ diagonal and $R$ with only $1$ on the diagonal. Then $A=LDR$ and $A=A^T=R^TDL^T$ and by the uniqueness of the LU decomposition, $R=L^T$. By the inertia theorem, the sign structure of $D$ is invariant, and thus the index can be computed from it.

Comment: What do you mean with "more generic"? LU or LDLT decomposition is as simple as it gets. There are easy modifications that allow for pivoting and to make $D$ on occasion tridiagonal to allow for $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ blocks. Note that LDLT is the algorithmic form of "completing the squares" of the quadratic form associated to the matrix.